# Finding the terminal velocity of a magnet dropped in a solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, velocity, magnetic-fields, induction

> We have to find proportionality of the terminal velocity with the factors of the system:
>   [image]
>
> Plot: a small dipole(mass $m$) with dipole moment $\mu$ is dropped in a long solenoid (radius $r$, Resistance $R\: \mathrm{\Omega}$) along it's axis. The gravity is acting downwards.

I found it to be $$v\propto \dfrac{mR}{\mu^2r}$$

Here is how:

> The force in downward direction $F_{down}$ must be $mg$ and in upward direction $F_{up}$ must be magnetic force.
>   $$F_{up}\propto \dfrac{\mu I_{induced}}{r}$$
>
> $$I_{induced}\propto\dfrac{ \text{electric flux change}}R \propto\dfrac{\mu \pi r^2 v}R$$

Flux change depends directly on the velocity, so added $v$ in the numerator.  But the expression is not correct.  The proportionality on the $r$ radius is not correct. I think there is a problem in the induced current factor.

Comment: Is current flowing in solenoid? Is that electric dipole or magnetic dipole?